# Webhook Switch Channel With Bot

Tags: discord.py

I want that when you use the command webhook should send the message in the channel where  the code is used.But I dont know how to do it please help.

```
   @bot.command()
    async def deneme(ctx, test):
         webhook = Webhook.partial(webhookid, webhooktoken, adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
    
         webhook.send(test, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your channel already has a created webhook you can get a list of all of the webhook of the channel the message is sent in by using `ctx.channel.webhooks()` picking one and getting its url by doing `WEBHOOK.url()`. If your channel does not have a webhook you can create one by using `await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name='WEBHOOK NAME')` you can assign this to a variable and get the url by using `WEBHOOK.url()`.

NOTE: Creating a webhook is only supported by discord.py-rewrite.

Alternatively you can just use your bot to reply instead of using a webhook by using `ctx.channel.send()`